# Why is my animation not working now that I've added counter variable and Intervals?

Tags: javascript, class, object, animation, p5.js

I have an animation function within a class.

The animation is of a tree 'shuddering' back and forth quickly along the x axis as if struck by an axe.

What I'd like to happen:

When I click on the tree the animation should start, stop, start, stop, start and then permanently stop. The ratio of animation running and stopped in my mind would be somewhere around 2s running, 8s stopped. The boundaries in which the animation stays within are very small (see the final if statement) with a speed of 4. Therefore the tree just bounces very quickly between the two giving the impression of a 'shudder'.

The function is inside a class which is called in function setup(). tree.shudder() however is called inside function draw() which is a looping function.

This is the code with one iteration/cycle of the working animation:

```
shudder() {
  let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
  let speed = 0;
  if (d < 50) {
    speed = 4;
    if (this.x < this.l || this.x > this.r) {
      speed = speed * -1;
    }
  } else {
  speed = 0;
  }
  this.x = this.x + speed;
}
```

The animation was working until I tried to automate the start & stop of the judder.
When I added the counter variable and setInterval/clearInterval functions the judder no longer works.

I'm using the p5 library.

Can anyone see why my animation has stopped working here?

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  trees = new Trees(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
  trees.shudder();
}

shudder() {
  let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
  let counter = 0;
  let speed = 0;
  if (d < 50) {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      speed = 4;
      counter++;
      console.log(counter);
      if (this.x < this.l || this.x > this.r) {
        speed = speed * -1;
      }
      if (counter === 3) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    }, 1000)
  } else {
    speed = 0;
  }
  this.x = this.x + speed;
}
```

In console.log if I click on the tree and let 60 frames go by this happens:

```
60trees.js:31 1
trees.js:31 2
trees.js:31 1
trees.js:31 2
2trees.js:31 1
2trees.js:31 2
```

and runs infinitely...

However, If I click on the tree and click off before 60 frames pass I get what I want:

```
26trees.js:31 1
26trees.js:31 2
26trees.js:31 3
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: It does not make sense to have `setInterval` defined in a function that is already itself subject of a similar construct (i.e. `draw`). But it is not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: When triggered, I want to have my animation happen three times and then stop.

Comment: Why do you not just check every frame whether the speed must be negated, instead of checking it only every second?

Comment: it just made no sense to me to put the else statement on the other two if statements.

Comment: since you are using p5 why not just let calls to draw handle your animation. You could have a counter that you set to zero and increment it inside of draw. There may be good reasons to use interval along with p5.js but if you are trying to do something simple you may very well be better off without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- `setInterval` executes when `d < 50`, which means it will execute several times in a row, without taking into account it had already executed. So you get a bunch of timers that will expire around the same time.
- the `counter` and `speed` that you modify in the `setInterval` callback refer to the variables as they were when `setInterval` was called, and have no effect on the subsequent calls of `shudder`, where these variables are new variable instances.
- You only check once every second to see if `this.x` is still within bounds. This should better be done at each frame during the animation.
- It just looks bad to have `setInterval` in a function that is called for every frame. It can work, but you need to be very careful how you do things.

I would go for a pattern where you calculate the end-time of the animation and just read out the current time to see if you're there yet. Also make sure to maintain state (in `this`) about speed and such...

Something like this:

```
shudder() {
    if (!this.steps) { // not yet (ever) animated?
        this.speed = 0;
        let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
        if (d < 50) {
            // Adapt these numbers to set the time at which animation should pause/restart:
            this.steps = [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500].map(i => Date.now() + i);
        }
    } else if (this.steps[0] < Date.now()) { // duration completed?
        this.speed = 4 - Math.abs(this.speed); // Toggle between animate and pause
        this.steps.shift(); // Remove a step, since that duration has completed
    }
    if (this.x < this.l || this.x > this.r) this.speed = -this.speed;
    this.x += this.speed;
}
```

Comment: You're a saint. Trying it out now. Can I need to declare this.speed in the constructor of my class or can I declare it locally in this function?

Comment: Properties are not declared but created, but you don't need to create it beforehand, it gets created when it doesn't exist by this code any way.

Comment: Why do I not need to enclose that final if statement with curly brackets? At the moment it's stopping 3 seconds after I click elsewhere.

Comment: You can add braces if you wish, and some feel it is a better coding style, but when what follows is just one statement, they are not needed.

Comment: The three seconds are defined by `+ 3000` in this code. Change it to the duration that you need.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help. Yea I know 3000 = 3s but I'd like it to stop on its own after a certain amount of time. i.e without any user input.

Comment: Well if `d < 50` it will kick in immediately after the previous animation. It is not clear to me what you want to happen then. Is there an extra condition you have in mind before the animation is allowed a second time? I did not find it in your question...

Comment: I've obviously gone down the wrong road here then. I just want to click on my tree, have the animation start, stop, start, stop, start and then stop permanently.

Comment: So what are the durations for these three animations, and the pauses between them. And should the pause coincide with the change in direction, or is there no relationship with that?

Comment: My thinking was to somehow cycle through an if statement a few times looping the on and off of the animation and then finally finishing with the else statement.

Comment: I was thinking something very basic for timings. half a second for on and half a second for off. No, no relationship. The pause can stop the tree where it likes.

Comment: This is getting too long for this comment section: could I ask you to edit the question and add all of the details of the desired behaviour in there? Assume that we know nothing of what you intended to do. Explain everything about the desired animation: what starts it, what stops it, when it can start again, how long the pauses should be, the number of them, ...etc. It is better like that than discussing here.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer with a new code snippet. You can adjust the times of start/stop/start/stop/start/stop (milliseconds) as desired.

Comment: Yep! You got it! Thanks very much!